# How to parse XML data into SQL query viewer

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a XML column in a SQL Server database that I need to be able to extract the data from, and spread into multiple columns in a SQL query. The table itself runs to multiple millions of rows of data.

The XML data is stored as:

```
<dreg>
    <dtype>Test</dtype>
    <dOS>Test</dOS>
    <dmake>Test</dmake>
</dreg>
```

When I try to run the SQL query below, the XML data is returned in the view as one column:

```
select 
    Id,
    dID,
    Meta /*<- XML data*/
from 
    data_table
```

However, if I run the following SQL query:

```
select 
    ID,
    dID,
    cast(Meta as XML).value('(/dreg)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as data
from 
    data_table
```

The resulting column 'data' in the viewer for the XML is:

```
TestTestTest
```

How do I parse the XML correctly, so that the 3 values in the XML are in separate columns in the SQL viewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this to extract the separate XML elements under `<dreg>` as separate values:

```
select 
    ID,
    dID, 
    DType = Meta.value('(/dreg/dtype)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    DOS = Meta.value('(/dreg/dOS)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    DMake = Meta.value('(/dreg/dmake)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') 
from 
    data_table
```

If `Meta` really is a column of type `XML`, there's absolutely no need for a `CAST(Meta AS XML)` ....

Comment: Do I need to call the ````data_table````, or will the ````@input```` do instead?

Comment: @Clauric: no, it should be `Data_table` - the `@input` was just for my own use - fixed the answer